# How present JSON List in Angular HTML with *ngFor

Tags: html, json, angular

I get a result in the JSON Format like these sample from a webservice.
How can i iterate over this items to prensent the objects

HTML Code - not working

```
<div *ngFor="let item of List">
  {{item.Code}}
</div>
```

JSON Sample

```
"List": {
  "0": {
         "Code": "A"
       },
  "1": {
         "Code": "B"
       },
  "2": {
         "Code": "C",
       }
  }
```

unfortunally the webservice does not provide this as an Array [] of objects

I want to see the list of all items für the Key "Code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was not working with

```
<div *ngFor="let item of List | keyvalue">
  {{item.value.Code}}
</div>
```

Typescript was throwing an error because {{item.value.Code}} was not known.

I did some additional research and found the following solution

```
<div *ngFor='let key of objectKeys(List)'>
  {{List[key].Code}} 
</div>
```

in the typescript class corresponding to the html file you have to add

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use KeyValuePipe like [here](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe).

So the your code would be something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of List | keyvalue">
  {{item.value.Code}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but with "let item in List" I get no results.
With "let item of List" I get results. I get an output for "item.keys" but I can not access item.value.Code. Typescript raises an Error. and for item.value I only see [object Object]

Comment: Yes, you have to use `let item of List`. I made a mistake there and edited the answer.